# Can I use an old Gemlock file contents as new Gem file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I have an old ROR app that is running Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 4.2.4, and MongoDB 3.0.  I need to move it to Ruby 2.2.2, Rails 4.5, and MongoDB 3.2.

I took over this project so the code is currently running on hosting service. I have downloaded source code. However, I wanted to build a simple scaffold app locally on my machine with the Gem file from the project that needs updating. First, the gem file of the project doesn't list specific versions of the gem, so if I try to use bundler it is trying to grab all the newer versions of the gems. The Gemlock file of the project does contain the version numbers being used.

My question is can I use the contents of the gemlock file (copy + paste) into my local Gem file then run bundler. Will this work properly, meaning will it get the proper gems (the versions being used on the production server)? I understand that some of those gem version might have been removed. Thinking I just comment those out of the gem file then run bundle install until it works.

```
    GIT
  remote: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby
  revision: df2e36287d88726c6a03ec6c1fdc19b5d6e2b274
  specs:
    stripe (1.27.2)
      json (~> 1.8.1)
      rest-client (~> 1.4)

PATH
  remote: ./vendor/plugins/mongoid-encrypted-fields-1.2.2
  specs:
    mongoid-encrypted-fields (1.2.2)
      mongoid

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.4)
      actionpack (= 4.2.4)
      actionview (= 4.2.4)
      activejob (= 4.2.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.4)
      actionview (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.4)
      activemodel (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.4)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.3.8)
    aescrypt (1.0.0)
    arel (6.0.3)
    aws-sdk (1.66.0)
      aws-sdk-v1 (= 1.66.0)
    aws-sdk-v1 (1.66.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
    axiom-types (0.1.1)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.4)
      ice_nine (~> 0.11.0)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    bson (3.2.4)
    bson_ext (1.5.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    chronic (0.10.2)
    coercible (1.0.0)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0.1)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    commander (4.3.5)
      highline (~> 1.7.2)
    daemons (1.2.3)
    debugger (1.6.8)
      columnize (>= 0.3.1)
      debugger-linecache (~> 1.2.0)
      debugger-ruby_core_source (~> 1.3.5)
    debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
    debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.8)
    descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.1)
    devise (3.5.2)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    domain_name (0.5.24)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    equalizer (0.0.11)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    ethon (0.8.0)
      ffi (>= 1.3.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.8)
    excon (0.45.4)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faraday (0.9.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    ffi (1.9.10)
    gcm (0.1.0)
      httparty
      json
    geocoder (1.2.11)
    gibberish (1.4.0)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    grape (0.13.0)
      activesupport
      builder
      hashie (>= 2.1.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.3.2)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
      rack (>= 1.3.0)
      rack-accept
      rack-mount
      virtus (>= 1.0.0)
    hashids (1.0.2)
    hashie (3.4.2)
    highline (1.7.7)
    houston (2.2.3)
      commander (~> 4.1)
      json
    http-cookie (1.0.2)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    httparty (0.13.7)
      json (~> 1.8)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    ice_nine (0.11.1)
    iron_core (1.0.9)
      rest (>= 3.0.4)
    iron_worker_ng (1.6.6)
      bundler
      iron_core (>= 1.0.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.0.0)
    jquery-rails (4.0.5)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    jwt (1.5.1)
    kaminari (0.16.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    libv8 (3.16.14.11)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mandrill-api (1.0.53)
      excon (>= 0.16.0, < 1.0)
      json (>= 1.7.7, < 2.0)
    mime-types (2.6.2)
    mimemagic (0.3.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.8.1)
    mongo (2.1.1)
      bson (~> 3.0)
    mongoid (5.0.0)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
      mongo (~> 2.1)
      origin (~> 2.1)
      tzinfo (>= 0.3.37)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    net-http-persistent (2.9.4)
    netrc (0.10.3)
    newrelic-grape (2.0.0)
      grape
      newrelic_rpm
    newrelic_rpm (3.13.2.302)
    nexmo (3.0.0)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    oauth2 (1.0.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    opentok (2.3.3)
      activesupport (>= 2.0)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      httparty (~> 0.13.1)
    origin (2.1.1)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-accept (0.4.5)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-cors (0.4.0)
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.4)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.4)
      actionpack (= 4.2.4)
      actionview (= 4.2.4)
      activejob (= 4.2.4)
      activemodel (= 4.2.4)
      activerecord (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.4)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.4)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.4)
    railties (4.2.4)
      actionpack (= 4.2.4)
      activesupport (= 4.2.4)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    ref (2.0.0)
    responders (2.1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5)
    rest (3.0.6)
      net-http-persistent (>= 2.9.1)
      netrc
    rest-client (1.8.0)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0)
      netrc (~> 0.7)
    rmagick (2.15.4)
    rubyzip (1.1.7)
    sendgrid-ruby (1.1.6)
      faraday (~> 0.9)
      mimemagic
      smtpapi (~> 0.1)
    smtpapi (0.1.0)
    sprockets (3.3.5)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    therubyracer (0.12.2)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    thin (1.6.4)
      daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    timecop (0.8.0)
    twilio-ruby (4.4.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.3.0)
    typhoeus (0.8.0)
      ethon (>= 0.8.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.1)
    virtus (1.0.5)
      axiom-types (~> 0.1)
      coercible (~> 1.0)
      descendants_tracker (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.3)
      equalizer (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.9)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  aescrypt
  aws-sdk (~> 1)
  bson_ext
  chronic
  debugger
  devise
  execjs
  factory_girl_rails
  gcm
  geocoder
  gibberish (~> 1.4.0)
  grape
  hashids
  houston
  iron_worker_ng
  jquery-rails
  kaminari
  mail
  mandrill-api
  mongo
  mongoid (~> 5.0.0)
  mongoid-encrypted-fields!
  newrelic-grape
  newrelic_rpm
  nexmo
  oauth2
  opentok (~> 2.2)
  rack-cors
  rails (~> 4.2.4)
  rails_12factor
  rmagick
  sendgrid-ruby
  stripe!
  therubyracer
  thin
  timecop
  twilio-ruby
  typhoeus
  uglifier
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bother about Gemfile.lock file, First you change the version of gems that you need to update in Gemfile which will update Gemfile.lock after bundle update.

e.g Change Gemfile to update rails version

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
```

to

```
gem 'rails', '4.5.0'
```

And simply `bundle update rails` this will update rails gem and it's dependencies.

But you want to update only rails without its dependencies(not recommended at least for gems like Rails)

```
e.g. bundle update --source rails
```

Refer [bundle update](https://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-update.1.html) command

PS: You can add ruby version(=2.2.2) in Gemfile which will automatically switch the ruby version if your are using rvm.

Comment: I think I might have confused you. I don't want to update my app yet. What I am trying to do first is create a new-app with the same CURRENT gems that are used in production (including exact version numbers being used). I want to do a test and update this new-app to see what gems all need to be updated when I switch the new-app to 2.2.2 and rails 4.5. I then plan to look up what the minimum version of GEMS needing updating are. Go look up those Gems to see what changes have been done between what is now needed (2.2.2/4.5) vs what the current production app is using now.

Comment: We have 0% test converage so I want to find out what has changed. Go fix any code. Then do the actual bundle update command on production level code and the app should have less errors.